# Install Derby Datebase in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, derby

I am new to Linux Ubuntu from Windows 10. I need assistance installing Apache Derby Database for Netbeans. I have the bin.taz.gz file already installed now I just need help installing and configuring it. Please assist

Answer (score 1):

You do have JDK and NetBeans installed, right? If so, you can follow this tutorial and unpack the Derby archive: https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html

An example installation could look like this (adapt your version numbers):

```bash
mkdir /opt/Apache
cp db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin.tar.gz /opt/Apache
cd /opt/Apache
tar xzvf db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin.tar.gz
```

You can put in your shell startup script (.bashrc or .zshrc, etc.):

```
export DERBY_INSTALL=/opt/Apache/db-derby-10.15.2.0-bin
export CLASSPATH=$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derbytools.jar:$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derbyoptionaltools.jar:$DERBY_INSTALL/lib/derbyshared.jar:.
```

And then according to the tutorial you need to execute that:

```
cd $DERBY_INSTALL/bin
. setEmbeddedCP

# verify Derby
java org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo
```

In NetBeans you can add the Derby installation as libraries or launch configuration but I am an Eclipse user and don't know NetBeans.
But I found a very good explanation here: https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html